# Why are my decks in Hearthstone locked?

Tags: hearthstone

When I try to build a new deck, my spare deck slots are all locked with the message "Unlock this deck by defeating other heroes in any mode." I can use decks that have already been created but I can't make any new decks.

I've been playing Hearthstone for a long time and have previously beat the tutorial - why are all my deck slots locked again?

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if you haven't unlocked the Demon Hunter class but have previously completed the tutorial. Complete the Ashes of the Outland Prologue in Solo Adventures to unlock the Demon Hunter class and your extra deck slots again.